# float a component on top of parent component in extjs

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs4.1, extjs-mvc

I asked this question before here but maybe because of lack of understanding, nobody answered it correct. I am tryin to have a `toolbar` (or something else which you want to recommend instead) on the `mouseenter` event of the parent container.

Right now, I the `toolbar` is being visible at the bottom of the parent container resizing the `container2` component which has `flex: 1`.

[image]

[image]

Here is my code:

```
var hContainer = [];  //adding many blocks to this dynamically
hContainer.push({
    xtype: 'panel',
    flex:1,             
    layout: {type:'vbox',align:'stretch'},                       
    items:[{
        xtype: 'container',
        height: 10,
        html: 'hello'
    },
    {
        xtype: 'container',
        flex: 1
    }]              
})
```

and then on `mouseenter` event of the parent container ie. `panel` adding the below variable something like this `parentContainer.add(upperController)`.

```
var upperController = {                                                              
   xtype: 'toolbar',                                                                  
   defaultAlign: 'tl',  //no effect at all                                                                 
   items: ['->',{                                                               
       xtype: 'button',                                                             
       text: '+'                                                              
   }]                                                   
}
```

Comment: Why don't you just have it default and only change it's visibility?

Comment: @Rob I don't want it to be in layout. It should be out of layout as I shown in the image. (above the `container1`)

Answer (score 3):

If it was me i would do the following: Container 1 and container 2 have lets say `flex: 1` and `flex: 2` to determine their height.

Get Container 1 to behave like a container and set an extra `layout: 'vbox'`, so that the height of container 1 will stay the same due to the `flex: 1` on the parent container.

You can then add items to container 1 without changing its height, because the `flex` of those children(items) will determine the height of those children(items).

Comment: Do you mean add items to `container 1` instead of adding to `parent container` ?

Comment: Yes, but only because you want `container 1` to be 'behind' the toolbar, which doesn't make a lot of sense to me. Why do you want that?

Comment: Yup this is working. the content is being behind even the `toolbar` is added to `container 1`. thanks. But anyway to attach to the parent container? (Because I just want to know about it)

Comment: Ofcourse this is possible, (i always think of the fact that it is just some html and css) but it would probably mean breaking out of the `comfortzone` and get going with `CSS` and `z-index`. I'm always a bit afraid when it comes to stuff like that, because it usually ends up with colliding css-rules and having to force css-behavior. Which ends up in unexpected result in other parts of your app (that's just my experience with it).

Comment: I am not sure how css will act with flex values to other child containers. I was looking for pure extjs answer though. Right now your post solved the problem of my issue. I will wait for other answers for a while.